# Adding buildFeatures { compose true } causes build to take indefinitely. How to investigate issue?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

After having a good experience with Jetpack Compose in new projects I decided to add Compose to an existing project of my company. After making all the necessary changes and writing the first lines of compose code I tried to build the project for the first time. Unfortunately, the build process gets stuck during *ui:compileDebugKotlin* multiple times (I waited for almost 45m and then stopped the build).

I never got any error message, all I could conclude is, that the problem arises after adding  `buildFeatures { compose true }` to my modules `build.gradle`. Without this line the build finishes within 3 seconds (-> It's not a performance issue)

I currently have no clue where to start cause I got no error. I cannot reproduce the issue in a plain project. How can I find the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out there are problems when using `kotlin-android-extensions`(which has been deprecated recently) and compose alongside each other in the same module (as of `compose-alpha09)`.

I had to migrate to viewBinding (which is very time time consuming) and remove `apply plugin: android-kotlin-extensions`

Being forced to migrate to viewBiding makes composes backwards compatibility pretty useless since it may take a lot of time to migrate. Also, an error message would have saved a ton of time.